# Update multiple labels in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a bokeh plot where, with a slider, it updates multiple labels.
The code I have below is a combination from two questions posed on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518254/trigger-display-of-the-hovertool-tooltips-via-customjs-in-bokeh) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680708/load-graph-data-from-files-on-button-click-with-bokeh).

In the code i have static x and y coordinates, its just the text labels that i want to manipulate with the slider. With code below it doesnt seem to show or even update. Why is it not showing and/or updating?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d, LabelSet, Label, Slider, TextInput, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

output_file("image.html")

plot = figure(x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 100))


source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=[55, 28, 18, 74, 76, 28, 32, 18, 60, 84, 44, 56, 56, 76],
        y=[8, 8, 33, 14, 72, 64, 46, 20, 52, 56, 84, 22, 36, 32],
        v1=prices_final["1"].values,
        v2=prices_final["2"].values,
        v3=prices_final["3"].values,
        v4=prices_final["4"].values,
    )
)

labels = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], t=[], ind=[]))
plot.add_layout(
    LabelSet(
        x="x",
        y="y",
        text="t",
        source=labels,
        level="overlay",
        x_offset=0,
        y_offset=0,
        render_mode="canvas",
        text_font_size="10pt",
        text_color="black",
        background_fill_color="white",
        border_line_color="black",
    )
)

# Set up widgets
slider = Slider(title="Hour of day", value=1.0, start=1.0, step=1.0, end=24.0)

code = """
    labels.data = {'x':[],'y':[],'t':[]}
    source.selected.indices = [slider.value]
    labels.data = {'ind':[slider.value],
            'x':[source.data.x],
            'y':[source.data.y],
            't':[source.data.v[slider.value]]}
    labels.change.emit()
    source.change.emit()
    """

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, slider=slider, labels=labels), code=code)
slider.js_on_change("value", callback)


layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

prices final looks like:

```
prices_final['1'].values = array([ -5.25,   2.67,  10.67,  -0.95,  -9.54,
   -4.22,  -5.2 ,  -5.53, -9.33,  -3.49,  -0.47,  -8.96, -17.88,  -5.49])
```

all other prices_final have similar data structure.

Comment: Can you provide more information like import modules, var prices_final, so that we could reproduce easily?

Comment: updated requested information

Comment: I have wrote a working sample. Please try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
This code shows a graph with sliders and v1, v2, .. values as labels. You'll need to change v1, ... v4 part. I couldn't write short with many v, so it might be very long with 24.

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, LabelSet
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource

x = [55, 28, 18, 74, 76, 28, 32, 18, 60, 84, 44, 56, 56, 76]
y = [8, 8, 33, 14, 72, 64, 46, 20, 52, 56, 84, 22, 36, 32]

label_selected = [''] * 14

# To simplify, make v1 to v4 with same num
v1 = [1] * 14
v2 = [2] * 14
v3 = [3] * 14
v4 = [4] * 14

# list of all v1,v2...
v = [v1, v2, v3, v4]

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(x=x, y=y, v=v, label_selected=label_selected)
)

plot = figure(x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 100), plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

plot.circle(x, y, radius=5, fill_color="red", fill_alpha=0.6, line_color=None)

slider = Slider(title="Hour of day", value=1.0, start=1.0, step=1.0, end=24.0)

code = """
    const data = source.data;
    const A = hour.value; /* hour starts from 1*/
    const x = data['x'];
    const y = data['y'];
    let label_selected = data['label_selected'];
    const v1 = data['v'][0];
    const v2 = data['v'][1];
    const v3 = data['v'][2];
    const v4 = data['v'][3];

    if (A == 1){
        label_list = v1
    } else if (A == 2) {
        label_list = v2
    } else if (A == 3) {
        label_list = v3
    } else if (A == 4) {
        label_list = v4
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < label_selected.length; i++){
        label_selected[i] = label_list[i]

    } 
    source.change.emit();
"""


callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(source=source, hour=slider),
    code=code
)

slider.js_on_change("value", callback)

labels = LabelSet(
    x="x",
    y="y",
    text="label_selected",
    level="glyph",
    x_offset=5,
    y_offset=5,
    source=source,
    render_mode="canvas",
)

plot.add_layout(labels)

layout = row(plot, column(slider))

output_file("slider.html", title="slider.py example")

show(layout)
```

Showing snapshot with slider 3... [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but it's not really what i was after, although it does show now. Basically what I want: in my code you can see I make multiple v's: v1 v2, v3 and in the end up until v24. I want to use the slider to call all of the values in a specific v, given the coordinates in x and y which will never change. So i want for example when the slider is on value 1, to show all of v1's values on the x and y coordinates. When i slide the slider to 2, it should call v2 with the same x and y. sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Then edited as use all of v1 (or v2...) as slider nums. Please try.